# Build from source

Tags: react-native

I tried to build react-native for iOS from source, regarding [official tutoral](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/react-native-cli#alternative-workflow):

1. Created alias for local react-native master branch
2. Changed line (~191)

`exec('npm install --save react-native', function(e, stdout, stderr) {`

to

`exec('npm install MY_ALIAS_RN', function(e, stdout, stderr) {`
 3. executed `react-native init AwesomeProject`

Everything installed, but when i try to run `react-native run-ios` i saw
[next message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsNKQ.png).

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

As the error message states, this is probably related to [Github Issue #4968](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968) Have you already tried any of the following workarounds?

1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`
2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`
3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`
4. Recreate project from scratch